# Postgresql and PHP prepared statements

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

Im trying to insert information into my postgres database using prepared statements. I know about the pg-prepare statement, my question is what is the equivalent to bindParam for postgresql? Maybe I'm misunderstanding how it all connects.

I've done the equivalent in mysql:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, position) VALUES (:name, :position)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':position', $pos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Postgresql seems to have its own set of statements to use like [pg_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php), [pg_insert](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-insert.php), pg_select, and pg_execute. I don't understand how they all work together. The us2[.]php.net/manual site doesn't have enough information.

I try to get started with insert, but then get lost when it comes to binding. They only have examples for selection.

```
$result = pg_insert($pdo, "query", '');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php ... It should work the same way in MySQL, PostegreSQL and anyone who implements PDO interface. So, have you tried using the same code?

Comment: They don't work together, the `pg_functions()` are separate from PDO.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to use the `pg_` functions instead of pdo?